# Why doesn't map read show (Integer) work to separate each value in a string of Integers?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm trying to learn how to separate one Integer with many numbers into an `[Integer]`, and I've seen a post about this before where they simply used the modulus 10 operator to find the last/remainder over and over and assigned that number to the beginning of an `[Int]`, but why can't you simply convert the number to a `String` (which I believe is equal to a `[Char]`) with the show function, then map the read function to each `Char` in the `[Char]` to get integer values in each spot of the `[Char]` to make an `[Integer]`?

The code I'm imagining is pretty much just like:

```
deconstructor :: Integer -> [Integer] //(or trying [Char])
deconstructor n
  | n < 0       = map read (show (n * (-1))) 
  | n == 0      = [read "0"] //(This line works)
  | otherwise   = map read (show n) //(or in [] or with :: [Integer] on the end)
```

The error it gives is always something along the lines of:

```
    * Couldn't match type `Char' with `[Char]'
      Expected: [String]
        Actual: String
```

Just processing `show n` compiles fine and gives a `String`/`[Char]`, and the way I understand map is that it just does the left thing (read in this case) to each index of the array on the right (the thing I'm imagining is a `[Char]`), so what is it that I'm not quite understanding? Would the `String` have to be already separated into different `[String]`s or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you have correctly diagnosed the problem.

The issue is that `read` must operate on a `String`, not a single `Char`.  If you `read "1234"`, you are applying `read` to a `String` and all is well, but if you `map read "1234"`, you are applying `read` to `('1' :: Char)`, then `('2' :: Char)`, and so on, and Haskell won't accept this mismatch of types.

You can convert each `Char` to a one-character `String` either using `singleton` from `Data.List` as part of your `map`:

```
import Data.List

... = map (read . singleton) (show n)
```

or you can use the function `(:[])` in place of `singleton`.  This is a "section" that does a cons `:` operation on each character (for the "head") and the empty list `[]` (for the "tail").  I mention this only because it's pretty common in Haskell code "in the wild", so you'll often see it used:

```
... = map (read . (:[])) (show n)
```

So, the following ought to work:

```
import Data.List (singleton)

deconstructor :: Integer -> [Integer]
deconstructor n
  | n < 0       = deconstructor (-n)
  | otherwise   = map (read . singleton) (show n)
```

Note that you don't really need the `n == 0` case because it's just a special case of the more general case.

Comment: Yup, I guess there was...

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I wanted to try doing it without importing anything and using the  `:[]` function worked perfectly. I don't quite understand how the cons operation/function works with the empty list to make read interpret the characters as,strings, but I'll definitely look into that further because that seems like a very important functionality. 

Also for the n==0 line, that makes perfect sense - I guess I was just imagining a special case where the length was only 1 and that number could be directly put into an array, though even then I could have probably just done [n] if not :[] haha

Comment: Also the only way I figured out that maybe it had to do with the fact they weren't strings was from that `n == 0` line when it wouldn't read in 0 unless it was double quoted instead of single quoted which I thought may have been a difference between a char and string declaration without an explicit `:: String` or what have you.

Now I want to test to see if I could make it work if I somehow declared something like `:: [String]`

Comment: I understand now that using the cons operator `:` to prefix an array implies that the thing before it is meant to be stored on the front of that array, so, by doing `map (read . (:[])) (show n`), we are really saying to map read(:[]) to every index of the string, or to every character, thus giving each character their own array and making each character their own character array/string. That is awesome.

Comment: In this case, I like list comprehensions syntax better than using `singleton` or `(:[])` (or `pure` or whatever), because it allows the use of mixfix syntax sugar for making the singleton list: `[read [c] | c <- show n]`.